# How can I select my version of python to use streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit

I have an app.py and I have several versions of python installed on my machine. How can I select what version of python should run when I type:

```
streamlit run app.py
```

Comment: Well, where did you `python -m pip install` it? It'll use the same python as that

Comment: No, that wasn't it. It would call a different python than the one I installed it on. The only way I got this work was by using the update-alternatives command to rename the default version of python.

Comment: It shouldn't use a different one, though. Since the other one(s) wouldn't have the streamlit module installed (AFAIK, the binary is just a wrapper on `python -m streamlit`) I'd suggest using pyenv rather than update-alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
python --version
```

**Output:** Python 3.8.8

This will be the version that your streamlit app will run on. In my case 3.8.8.

If you want to have a different version of Python for streamlit, you can install it from python.org, use a [virtual environment](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) , or use conda to create a specific environment with `conda install python 3.6.0`